# Checking and breaking out of a do-while loop

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am sending serial data to my android device from an external Bluetooth device as follows:

Send '*' ----> Send data----> Send '#'

Can somebody tell me why this code is not working? It is not displaying anything.

At the receiver end the code is as follows:
BluetoothChat.java

```
public String myteststring;
private static boolean check=true;

// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {

            case MESSAGE_READ:

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                if(!readMessage.matches("\\*")) {
                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Error!");
                    check=false;
                }

                do {
                    if(readMessage.matches("\\*")) {
                        mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Start");
                        myteststring = " ";

                    } else if(readMessage.matches("\\#")) {
                        mConversationArrayAdapter.add(myteststring);
                        mConversationArrayAdapter.add("End");
                        break;
                    } else  {
                        //mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
                        myteststring=myteststring.concat(readMessage);
                    }

                } while(check);

             case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    //code
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part isn't working? What is actually happening?

Comment: Its not displaying anything..

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the formatting makes it hard to read which makes it difficult to comment on. I would recommend either doing some logging and seeing what gets spat out or [attaching a debugger](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects-cmdline.html) and making sure your code points get hit and verify it that way.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing somethnig, but where is the actual part that would display anything?